# MATLAB - Frequency of an array element with a condition

Tags: matlab

I need some help please. I have an array, as shown below, 6 rows and 5 columns, none of the elements in any one row repeats. The elements are all single digit numbers. 
I want to find out, per row, when a number, let's say 1 appears, I want to keep of how often the other numbers of the row appear. For example, 1 shows up 3 times in rows one, three and five. When 1 shows up, 2 shows up one time, 3 shows up two times, 4 shows up two times, 5 shows up one time,  6 shows up two times,  7 shows up one time, 8 shows up three times,  and 9 shows up zero times. I want to keep a vector of this information that will look like, `V = [3,1,2,2,1,2,1,3,0]`, by starting with a vector like `N = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

```
ARRAY =
    1     5     8    2    6
    2     3     4    6    7 
    3     1     8    7    4
    6     5     7    9    4
    1     4     3    8    6
    5     7     8    9    6
```

The code I have below does not give the feedback I am looking for, can someone help please? Thanks

```
for i=1:length(ARRAY)
    for j=1:length(N)
        ARRAY(i,:)==j
        V(j) = sum(j)         
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how you are approaching the problem with your sample code but here is something that should work. This uses `find`, `any` and `accumarray` and in each iteration for the loop it will return a `V` corresponding to the ith element in `N`

```
for i=1:length(N)
    rowIdx = find(any(A == N(i),2)); % Find all the rows contain N(j)
    A_red = A(rowIdx,:); % Get only those rows
    V = [accumarray(A_red(:),1)]'; % Count occurrences of the 9 numbers
    V(end+1:9) = 0; % If some numbers don't exist place zeros on their counts
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using indices that is in `A` creae a zero and one  6 * 9 matrix that  [i,j] th element of it is 1 if i th row of A contains j.

Then multiply the zero and one matrix with its transpose to get desirable result:

```
A =[...
    1     5     8    2    6
    2     3     4    6    7 
    3     1     8    7    4
    6     5     7    9    4
    1     4     3    8    6
    5     7     8    9    6]
% create a matrix with the size of A  that each row contains the row number
rowidx = repmat((1 : size(A,1)).' , 1 , size(A , 2))
% z_o a zero and one  6 * 9 matrix that  [i,j] th element of it is 1 if i th row of A contains j
z_o = full(sparse(rowidx , A, 1))
% matrix multiplication with its transpose to create desirable result. each column relates to number N
out = z_o.' * z_o
```

**Result**: each column relates to N

```
   3   1   2   2   1   2   1   3   0
   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   0
   2   1   3   3   0   2   2   2   0
   2   1   3   4   1   3   3   2   1
   1   1   0   1   3   3   2   2   2
   2   2   2   3   3   5   3   3   2
   1   1   2   3   2   3   4   2   2
   3   1   2   2   2   3   2   4   1
   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   1   2
```